# As a symbolic link to sudo, why sudoedit has different behavior

Tags: shell, command, sudo, symlink

I have recently learned two neat command, `sudoedit` and `sudo -e`, which helps me to edit a non-writable file with my favorite editor' configuration enabled. Also, I thought that the `sudoedit` command is just a wrapper that pass `-e` flag to `sudo`. However, I found that the `sudoedit` command is just a symbolic link to `sudo`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    4 Jun 22 04:49 sudoedit -> sudo
```

So I wonder, as a symbolic link, why `sudoedit` has different behavior to `sudo`? How does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

It is kinda buried in Lajos Arpad's answer ("when invoked as sudoedit"...).

The "how does it happen" is something you can find out by looking for "unix argv" or similar using your favorite search engine, but in a nutshell:
if you write a program in C, your main function is given as parameter an array of arguments (conventionally called "argv"); by *convention* argv[0] should be the program name, and while things can get complicated ([https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/Argv0IsEasy](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/unix/Argv0IsEasy) - tldr you can pass *anything* as argv[0]) the important bit is that a program can *look* at argv[0] and decide eg that "if argv[0] is (somename) then do (something)".

Guess what? If you invoke a program via a symlink (and don't do anything horrible), argv[0] is the name of that symlink...

As a simple test, write `echo "$0($*)"` into a shell script, say foo.sh, make it executable (`chmod +x foo.sh`), create a symlink to it (`ln -s foo.sh mysymlink`) and see the difference when you run `./foo.sh 1 2 3` vs `./mysymlink 1 2 3`

Answer (score 0):

If you run `man sudoedit`, then you see a long manual page, I'm only pasting the relevant parts:

> ```
> NAME
>     sudo, sudoedit — execute a command as another user
>
> SYNOPSIS
>     [...]
>     sudoedit [-ABknS] [-C num] [-D directory] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-R directory] [-r role] [-t type] [-T timeout] [-u user] file ...
>
> DESCRIPTION
>     [...]
>     When invoked as sudoedit, the -e option (described below), is implied.
>
>     [...]
>     -e, --edit  Edit one or more files instead of running a command.  In lieu of a path name, the string "sudoedit" is used when consulting the security policy.  If the user
>                 is authorized by the policy, the following steps are taken:
>
>                 1.   Temporary copies are made of the files to be edited with the owner set to the invoking user.
>
>                 2.   The editor specified by the policy is run to edit the temporary files.  The sudoers policy uses the SUDO_EDITOR, VISUAL and EDITOR environment variables
>                      (in that order).  If none of SUDO_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, the first program listed in the editor sudoers(5) option is used.
>
>                 3.   If they have been modified, the temporary files are copied back to their original location and the temporary versions are removed.
>
>                 To help prevent the editing of unauthorized files, the following restrictions are enforced unless explicitly allowed by the security policy:
>
>                 •  Symbolic links may not be edited (version 1.8.15 and higher).
>
>                 •  Symbolic links along the path to be edited are not followed when the parent directory is writable by the invoking user unless that user is root (version
>                    1.8.16 and higher).
>
>                 •  Files located in a directory that is writable by the invoking user may not be edited unless that user is root (version 1.8.16 and higher).
>
>                 Users are never allowed to edit device special files.
>
>                 If the specified file does not exist, it will be created.  Note that unlike most commands run by sudo, the editor is run with the invoking user's environment
>                 unmodified.  If the temporary file becomes empty after editing, the user will be prompted before it is installed.  If, for some reason, sudo is unable to up‐
>                 date a file with its edited version, the user will receive a warning and the edited copy will remain in a temporary file.
>      [...]
> ```

So, `sudoedit` is equivalent to `sudo -e`, therefore, the difference between `sudo` and `sudoedit` is the very same as the difference between `sudo` and `sudo -e`, that is:

> Edit one or more files instead of running a command

Comment: However, this does not solve my question: As a symbolic link to `sudo`, when I type `sudoedit <path>`, I think it should act exactly like I type `sudo <path>`, but actually it's not.

Comment: @huibosa `sudo` is running a command. `sudo -e` is using the `-e` modifier in order to edit file(s) rather than running a command. If you run `sudo -e`, do you expect it to behave in the very same manner as if you run `sudo` without the `-e`?